# Problemas para carregar jquery no laravel

Tags: laravel-5, jquery-ui

Boa tarde, não estou conseguindo carregar o jquery no meu laravel, estou linkando corretamente as pastas:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery/jquery-ui.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js') }}" defer></script>
```

porem as paginas não carregam, alguem tem uma dica?

agradeço desde ja.

Answer (score -1):

beleza?

Então, essas chamadas estão no footer do site?

Se tiver em alguma página especifica, você pode usar o `@stack`

```
@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

E no arquivo que vai ter o fechamento do `<body>`, antes você põe @stack('scripts')`

Espero ter ajudado!